# accordion menu using struts2 / tiles / remote data

Tags: java, struts2, tiles

Can someone please post a sample code that shows acordion menu using struts2/tiles please.  I am struggling to get the accordion list by following the showcase example, which has the annotations...Thanks

Menu.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<link href="<s:url value="/pages/stylesheets/skins/blue.css"/>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <head>
    <sj:head jqueryui="true"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <s:url id="urlecho" action="echo"/>
    <sj:accordion 
        list="accordion" 
        paramKeys="echo" 
        paramValues="content" 
        href="%{urlecho}" 
        active="false" 
        autoHeight="false" 
        clearStyle="true" 
        listKey="title" 
        listValue="content"/>  
</body>
```

struts.xml

```
<action name="echo" class="com.accel.prjmgt.action.MenuAction">
    <result name="success" type="json">/pages/Menu.jsp</result>
</action>
```

MenuAction.java

```
public class MenuAction extends ActionSupport
{
    private List<AccordionDO> accordion;

    public String execute() throws Exception 
    {
        accordion = new LinkedList<AccordionDO>();
        accordion.add(new AccordionDO("My Title 1", "Content One"));
        accordion.add(new AccordionDO("My Title 2", "Content Two"));
        accordion.add(new AccordionDO("My Title 3", "Content Three"));
        accordion.add(new AccordionDO("My Title 4", "Content Four"));
        accordion.add(new AccordionDO("My Title 5", "Content Five"));

        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public List<AccordionDO> getAccordion() {
        return accordion;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.  Maybe I am asking a stupid question, but I am a beginner trying to learn S2 / tiles / JQuery please, so hope you guys understand and help.

Regards

Yuva

Comment: Do you know JavaScript/jQuery?

Comment: I would recommend going the jquery web site and look at the jquery-ui components (http://jqueryui.com/accordion/). Understanding how that works is half the problem, getting data from the server is the other half, Jaiwo99 shows configuration of an action using the struts2-json-plugin which is a pretty good way to get data from the server.

Comment: Thanks Quaternion, yes I know javascript and am learning jquery now.  When I run the above example, am getting a blank page loaded.  no errors or exception logged.  Have tried adding a comment line to my action file, to print on the console, but nothing is printed. I have a doubt that the request is not coming to the server at all.

Comment: Well if nothing is printed to the console... it probably isn't. The problem as mentioned has two parts. If you type in the URL to the action in chrome browser it will show the json in the browser (or better figure out how firebug works). If not there is very clearly a problem with the action. After that it is all jQuery, that is getting the data with jQuery.getJson() and working with the jquery-ui accordion. You should be able to insulate the struts2 concerns from the jquery concerns in the questions you ask. If you do you will get much better answers.

Comment: Hi thanks again,  I modified my code and my action file is now a tree like sample, which I would like to show it as an accordion. I am getting the content displayed on browser as follows:             {"data":{"Accordion 1":[{"content":"Content One","title":"Title 1"},{"content":"Content Two","title":"Title 2"},{"content":"Content Three","title":"Title 3"},{"content":"Content Four","title":"Title 4"},{"content":"Content Five","title":"Title 5"}]}.  I referred to this url and chgd my code :https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/struts2-jquery/9YsccWPRbyg.

Comment: As an additional info, what I am looking at is, something like the title of the accordion item would display ACCORDION 1, inside which it should display sub items, CONTENT 1, CONTENT 2, CONTENT 3, etc, each having a seperate href urls which I can click to go to the menus..  Hope I have given enough inputs.  I am using struts2-jquery-plugin-2.5.0.jar, and struts2-json-plugin-2.2.1.jar.  Kindly let me know if you need any further info.  I think I need to use iterator, but not getting it right..                            Thanks for your time.  Yuva

Comment: Best thing to do... post a new question. ONLY show that JSON string (as far as the server side details go), tag the question "jquery" and "jquery-ui" and make no mention of struts. Also create an example block of HTML the way you want it to look and comment the sections where you want the json to show up and comment where you want it to loop. The jquery community is lightning fast at answering well defined questions. The trick to getting answers however is not confusing them with any particular server side technology.

Answer (score 0):

change your action configuration to:

```
<action name="echo" class="com.accel.prjmgt.action.MenuAction">
    <result name="success" type="json"></result>
</action>
```

Comment: Thanks Jaiwo99 for your time, I tried your suggestion, and also added a line in execute() function, to print on the console.  But nothing was printed after successful login.  What I need is, when a user logs in successfully, the user should be taken to homepage alongwith dynamic menus retrieved from the database.  But I saw no request being printed on the actionfile.  Can you suggest me please.